# Django SaaS multiple users for one client

Tags: django, multi-tenant, saas, multi-user

I hope you are all safe and not too crazy yet :)

Here is my use case:

Company A signs up and creates an account and can add 5 additional users / employees to be able to login and see all that companies info and no other. Now Company B signs up and can add 15 additional user / employees as they have a higher tier plan and same thing they can't see the other company. Since this is not highly sensitive data, I'll just use a low level isolation ie. "SELECT * FROM 'table' WHERE tenant_uuid = 1"

This is the first time looking at the whole multi-tenant thing, and I sorta get that but I am struggling to see how I can have multiple users tied to the one account.

The only thing I can think of is an abstract user that has a FK to the company. The company would be created with the owner user attached to the company, a custom model manager will accomplish this and then the owner can go in and add his employees.

Is this my solution or has anyone seen or used something different? any help in the matter would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you look into django-tenant-schemas library? What it does is basically create a different schema in db for each tenant and then based on the host name it reads data from that specific schema. For example Company A will only have access to the data in schema_a and Company B will have access to schema_b. 
it only works with Postgres DB. 
https://django-tenant-schemas.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: I am looking at django-tenant, but I missed in the docs at each schema could add unlimited users basically, and my logic would limit the amount, but have been told that django-tenant is exactly what I need.